# python input() and signal interrupt

Tags: python, stdin, keyboardinterrupt

I have a console program that runs in loop and I am using Ctrl-C to pause execution of the loop and enter a menu. The shortest distillation of the issue is shown below:

```
from signal import signal, SIGINT

token = [None]

def handle_interrupt(a,b):
    if token:
        token.pop()
        
signal(SIGINT,handle_interrupt)

while True:
    if token:
        continue
    else:
        while True:
            response = input('enter a character > ')
            if not response:
                print('invalid response')
                continue
            break
        break
```

On my Windows machine, the code works as expected. On another user's Windows machine, when Ctrl-C is pressed, the user receives multiple `invalid response` notifications without any keystrokes other than the original Ctrl-C.

Why is this occurring? How is python's `input` function and the `stdin` stream affected by the Ctrl-C keystroke?

Comment: Is the same version of python, and all the necessary modules installed properly the other Users machine?

Comment: Yes, same version (3.7) and same modules.